# 404 Error when sending a request to a my local server

Tags: reactjs, express, backend, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to send a POST request to my server, but i am getting 404 error code in return.

Frontend (Vite + React):

```
async function submitBtn () {
    var data={
      password:Password,
      login:Login
    }
    alert('Login: ' + Login + ' Password: ' + Password)
    const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
    const body = JSON.stringify({
      jsonData
    })
    const config = {
      "headers":{
        "Content-Type":"application/json"
      }
    }
    try{
      const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:5173/api/data', body, config)
      console.log(response)
    } catch(error){
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
```

Backend (ExpressJS):

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 5173;
app.use(express.json()); // Enable JSON parsing

app.post('/api/data', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body); // Log the received data
  res.status(200).json({ message: 'Data received successfully' });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

I'm pretty sure my server is running, but it doesn't work at all

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP 404 error code, aka "Page not found" error indicates that the server couldn't locate the requested content at the given URL or path.

In your backend, you are only handling GET requests for "/api/data" by using `app.get("/api/data", ...)`. The server couldn't find a way to handle a POST request at "/api/data", therefore you need to use `app.post("/api/data", ...)` as well.

In your case I believe you meant to handle only the POST request for "/api/data", so the Backend code would be like this:

```
app.post('/api/data', (req, res) => { // Change get to post
  console.log(req.body); // Log the received data
  res.status(200).json({ message: 'Data received successfully' });
});
```

Comment: Oh yeah, totally forgot that i changed it, still get the error tho